MySQL 8 cannot drop a database or table due to an error stating 'dictionary object id does not exist'
I am unable to drop a MySQL8 database or table as it is giving me the following two errors. Despite searching online, I have not found any solutions to similar issues. Is there any way to proceed with the drop operation?

Drop the table or database with these errors.

mysql> use oa;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+--------------+
| Tables_in_oa |
+--------------+
| gzrb_bsqk    |
| lcl_xf_0728  |
| lh_left      |
| v_2021       |
| v_depts      |
| v_tyxm_ygs   |
| v_yuc        |
+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> create table lcl_xf_0728(id int);
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'lcl_xf_0728' already exists
mysql> drop table lcl_xf_0728;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'oa.lcl_xf_0728'
mysql> drop table gzrb_bsqk;
ERROR 3508 (HY000): Dictionary object id (6536868) does not exist.
mysql> drop database oa;
ERROR 3508 (HY000): Dictionary object id (6536868) does not exist.


I attempted to set innodb_force_recovery=1/2/3/4/5/6, but after restarting the MySQL instance, I still encountered the same error. I also tried upgrading from version 8.0.30 to 8.0.38 using the binary package, but it failed to start successfully. I had to revert back to version 8.0.30. The error message is provided below. It seems like it might be the same issue.

Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost systemd: Started MySQL8 Server.
Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:04.608309Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please 
use authentication_policy instead.
Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:04.608338Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/software/8/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.38) starting as process 19508
Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:04.620120Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012363] [InnoDB] innodb-page-size has been changed from the default value 16384 to 32768.
Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:04.620179Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have
 been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=8589934592. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
Jul 19 21:39:04 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:04.623156Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
Jul 19 21:39:11 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:11.855492Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost kernel: boot[19569]: segfault at 508 ip 0000000002170c8e sp 00007f7e5ce84b90 error 4
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: 2024-07-19T13:39:14Z UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: BuildID[sha1]=96a3ee772d1d213bc36262ae5f5c23c7b9f61b30
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: Thread pointer: 0x0
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost mysqld: terribly wrong...
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost systemd: mysqld8.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost systemd: Unit mysqld8.service entered failed state.
Jul 19 21:39:14 localhost systemd: mysqld8.service failed.

I cannot drop this database and these tables, and upgrading the MySQL instance failed. Can anyone help me?
I want to drop this database or tables.

[2024-07-30] The latest issue is that even after deleting the database directory, I am still unable to drop this database normally
mysql> drop database oa;
ERROR 3679 (HY000): Schema directory './oa/' does not exist
mysql> drop table oa.gzrb_bsqk;
ERROR 3508 (HY000): Dictionary object id (6536868) does not exist.
mysql> show tables from oa;
+--------------+
| Tables_in_oa |
+--------------+
| gzrb_bsqk    |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

I can still query this table from information_schema.tables. I believe the issue is due to the presence of this record in information_schema.tables. How can I remove it?
mysql> select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='oa';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema='oa'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: def
   TABLE_SCHEMA: oa
     TABLE_NAME: gzrb_bsqk
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: InnoDB
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Dynamic
     TABLE_ROWS: 4294967295
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 4294967295
    DATA_LENGTH: 4294967295
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 4294967295
   INDEX_LENGTH: 4294967295
      DATA_FREE: 4294967295
 AUTO_INCREMENT: 4294967295
    CREATE_TIME: 2022-08-29 16:03:28
    UPDATE_TIME: 2106-02-07 14:28:15
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS: 
  TABLE_COMMENT: 
1 row in set (0.01 sec)


Have you tried using command drop view lcl_xf_0728;. From the documentation, Looks like SHOW TABLES command also list both views and tables instead of just table.

use 'SHOW FULL TABLES', as per @taxevader, its most likely a VIEW

Thanks @tax evader, the other tables or views were dropped successfully, but the databases 'oa' and table 'gzrb_bsqk' still cannot be dropped. It still prompts the following error. Is there any other reason? I can no longer see any ibd files in the oa database directory. Is it caused by an abnormal table data file? How can I fix it?

mysql> show full tables;
+--------------+------------+
| Tables_in_oa | Table_type |
+--------------+------------+
| gzrb_bsqk    | BASE TABLE |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> drop table gzrb_bsqk;
ERROR 3508 (HY000): Dictionary object id (6536868) does not exist.

mysql> drop database oa;
ERROR 3508 (HY000): Dictionary object id (6536868) does not exist.


@congyu Hmm error 3508 seems pretty rare, the one case I found online is here , you might need to rm the database directory from the file system

I'm not too confident with this approach though

Thanks @tax evader, I'll try moving the database directory to another location and check if it is normal.

It's still not normal
